# Prevent R variable being modified/throw warning on non-assignment

Tags: r

In my stats classes many students have problems because they create dplyr pipelines that over-write existing variable names. They also forget to assign the output of their function calls to new variables.

Is there a way I can:

- prevent reassignment of variables, especially if the variable has previously been a data frame. Alternatively print a warning message when over-writing an existing global variable.
- print a warning when using any dplyr functions without assigning the result to a variable

```r
# this should throw an error or print warning
a <- tibble(a=1)
a <- tibble(a=2)


# this should also throw a warning, something like: 
# "Remember to create a new variable when processing data, use '<-'"
mtcars %>% filter(am==1)

# this is what the student should have done
amcars  <- mtcars %>% filter(am==1)
```

Note - all students are working on an RStudio server and we could insist they run a script/package when starting to work or put this in their .rprofile or similar.

Comment: IMO, sounds like a good learning experience. Providing some hacky fix/warning for them will just cause them problems down the line in the real world. They need to learn how to be more attentive to details. Just my opinion as somebody who hires and is often frustrated by unprepared college hires.

Comment: @Adam, agreed it's not a long term solution, but this i) wouldn't suppress the real error — this gets shown too — but ii) would direct their attention to where the error is so they start to learn and pay attention to the correct things. At present it's not really a good learning experience because as total beginners they just get stuck and upset (and so become avoidant about practice exercises)

Comment: Fair enough. It's hard to know what approach to actually take. Can only focus on so many things at once.